# new channels shown by week

Tags: ee2, channel-entries

i have made this code to generate the new entries wich have been posted.

```
<div class="nieuwe_berichten">
  {exp:channel:entries channel="interne_memo" display_by="week" limit="1" show_current_week="yes"}
    {total_results} nieuwe berichten!
  {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

This code generates only: “2 nieuwe berichten” and also 2 times. Does anybody know how to write a good code for this?

thnx in advance,
Leon vd Leer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="interne_memo"
    display_by="week"
    limit="1"
    show_current_week="yes"}
    {if no_results}0 nieuwe berichten{/if}

    {!-- your display for each entry here --}

    {if {count} == {total_results}}
        {total_results} nieuwe berichten! 
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Update:**
Revisiting this question, I can't work out why limit is in the parameters, as this will always force only 1 entry to return. This would surely be better:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="interne_memo"
    display_by="week"
    dynamic="no"
    show_current_week="yes"}
```

Comment: thnx! it's working!!

Comment: Can you mark it as correct answer to complete it please.

Comment: Hi @LeonvdLeer - if you found this helpful, please don't forget to come back and mark it as "accepted" (using the check box on the left). This tells others that it is the correct solution.

Comment: Ok this was working, but now: when i aply a new memo it says "2 nieuwe berichten" but it is always showing: "1 nieuwe berichten" is it possible to get the return, 0?

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't make sense: it says "2 nieuwe berichten" but shows "1 nieuwe berichten" - which is it?!? Assuming you mean there are 2 and it's displaying 1, I think the problem is limit="1" which I copied from your original - remove it.

Comment: Sorry Peter, for making you confuse...... maybe when you look at it it makes sense: http://www.vlaamschbroodhuys.nl/intern It always says "1 nieuwe berichten" and when i put a new entry it also says "1 nieuwe berichten" and put an other then it says "2 nieuwe berichten" so it only counts when theres more than 1 new entry in that week. I think there has to be an other if statement for the count of 0? Thnx a lot, for helping me out!

Comment: Is the limit parameter the issue? Are you using the offset parameter? {total_results} will be all the entries pulled back from the tag, so if it's missing one, there's a reason elsewhere in the template or relating to the tag in question. Maybe the URL and dynamic variable? Still unsure regarding the limit and if that's limiting the entries (I expect so) rather than restrict it to one week - wouldn't know without trying it.

Comment: this is the code which is used: (so no offset involved): {exp:channel:entries 
    channel="interne_memo"
    display_by="week"
    dynamic="no"
    show_current_week="yes"}
    {if {count} == {total_results}}
    <ul><li>
  <h3>{total_results} nieuwe berichten!</h3>
 </li></ul>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: I have found something new: when i remove all of the entries i just get nothing, so no result (no text, it would be great if it would say: "0 nieuwe berichten"). When i have some old entries (older then the past week) and no new entries i get "1 nieuwe berichten" and when i put a new entry in it i get also "1 nieuwe berichten" and when i put an other new entry i get "2 nieuwe berichten"...... so it seems to me verry strange and i have also looked furter on the internet and i have found nothing to get me anny further.

Comment: {if no_results} will sort your first issue - example updated.  Try outputting {count} and {total_results} in the middle of the tag, to see what is happening as each entry is displayed.

Comment: Super that is working for me!!! thnx a lot Peter Lewis