# How to show entries for next week or last week

Tags: date, orderby, entry-date

Related to this question [*new channels shown by week*](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12357/new-channels-shown-by-week)
How could you show entries, not for the current, but for next week?

If you have many future entries, `show_future_entries="yes" display_by="week" limit="1"`
will show one week worth of entries, but it's showing the furthest away future entries.

What are some of the options to display entries for next week?

Answer (score 2):

You could enable php, grab the current time and add as much time as you need, then use the [start_on](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on) parameter.

Or here's a plugin you could use:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin

Maybe something like this as the start_on parameter:
{exp:dt day="7" ee_format="true" format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}